# note pad/ leave comment widget

Tags: android

I am looking for a widget that I can use. What am after is when a user hits my tab button a activity start and this activity is for users to leave a comment or tip for what there looking for. I want the users to have something like 100 word limit. Is there anything that I can use to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a modified AlertDialog class with a submit and cancel button?

[Alert Dialog How To](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog)

Comment: iv looked into it but its not what am looking for but thanks stephen. something like this comment box ;)